# Bind KendoUI for Angular2 DropDownList or Combobox to a DataQuery

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

The [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/combobox/#toc-data-binding) mentions

> It also supports binding to an asynchronous source

But does not provide an example on how one would do this.  Please advise how one would go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the combobox to your async data and it will automatically detect observable updates or promise resolution

```
<kendo-combobox [data]="tickers" [valuePrimitive]="false" [textField]="'name'" >
</kendo-combobox> 
/* Obtain tickers from async operation */
```

Answer (score 0):

Binding to asynchronous data (Observables) is done through the [async pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html).
The documentation should be improved with a specific example such as:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/bufferCount';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <kendo-combobox [data]="tickers | async"></kendo-combobox>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    /* Start with an empty observable */
    public tickers: Observable<number[]>;

    constructor() {
        /* Produce 1 random value each 1000ms
           and emit it in batches of 10. */
        this.tickers = Observable.interval(100)
            .bufferCount(10);
    }
}
```